webkit-backface-visibility not working for ios/safari in TailwindCSS
I wrote the code for a 'social card' using tailwindCSS.
The code works perfectly fine for Windows/Android, but for iOS/Safari the rotation around y (rotate-y-180) glitches and the backface-hidden is applying but after 200-300ms delay.
I attach the div(s) code below where I apply the logic of it.
<div
                  className="relative w-full h-full **preserve-3d transition-all duration-[700ms] transform hover:rotate-y-180** 
              ease-[cubic-bezier(0.9,-0.5,0.2,1.7)]"
                >
                  {/* Face of the card */}
                  <div className=" w-full h-full bg-[url('@/assets/media/socialcard-background1.jpg')] bg-cover rounded-xl border-white/10 border-[1px] ">
                    <div
                      className=" **backface-hidden ** absolute w-full h-full inset-0 rotate-y-0 
                              rounded-xl bg-slate-300/10
                             cursor-pointer backdrop-filter backdrop-blur-[3px] bg-opacity-10"
                    >
                      <div className=" w-full h-[7rem] rounded-t-xl overflow-hidden " />
                      <div className="relative  w-[8.4rem] h-[8.6rem] mx-auto -mt-20">
                        
                        {/* Blur */}
                        <div className="absolute inset-0 w-[8.4rem] h-[8.4rem] bg-gradient-to-b from-white to-white/30 blur-xl opacity-60 rounded-full z-0"></div>

                        
                        <div className=" relative rounded-full w-[8rem] h-[8rem] lg:w-[8.4rem] lg:h-[8.4rem] z-10 ">
                          <img
                            src={myLogo}
                            alt="my name"
                            className="w-full h-full object-cover rounded-full  "
                          />
                        </div>
                      </div>

                      <div className="flex flex-col items-center pt-5 xl:pt-6">
                        <h1 className="text-center font-oswald  text-xl lg:text-2xl xl:mb-1">
                          My name
                        </h1>
                        <div className="flex flex-row items-center justify-center py-2 pr-2 lg:pt-3">
                        ....
                        ....
                        </div>

                        <div className="rounded-full border border-n-1 mt-2 px-2 lg:mt-7 xl:mt-10">
                          <p className="font-oswald px-0.5 pb-0.25 font-light text-xl lg:text-2xl ">
                            <span className="lg:hidden">Click</span>
                            <span className="max-lg:hidden">Hover</span> to find
                            me
                          </p>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  {/* Back of the card */}

                  <div
                    className="**backface-hidden** absolute inset-0 rotate-y-180
                              w-full h-full bg-[url('@/assets/media/socialcard-background1.jpg')] bg-cover rounded-xl"
                  >
                    <div className="flex items-center justify-center w-full h-full bg-slate-300/10 rounded-xl">
                      <div className="flex items-center gap-3">
                        ....
                        ....
                        ....
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>

I tried to override the plugin for backface-hidden (and also for preserve-3d)
plugins: [
    plugin(function ({ addUtilities }) {
      addUtilities({
        ".backface-hidden": {
          "backface-visibility": "hidden",
          "-webkit-backface-visibility": "hidden !important",
        },
        ".preserve-3d": {
          "transform-style": "preserve-3d",
          "-webkit-transform-style": "preserve-3d !important",
        },
      });
    })]

webkit-backface-visibility marked as !important
I tried many ideas from other posts but none of them solve my bug.
Any ideas?
